# Buzzing noise from speakers when using USB audio interface

Tags: usb, audio, noise, speakers, interference

I hearing a continuous fairly high pitched buzzing noise from my speakers as soon as I plug in my M-audio 2x2m audio interface into my computer.

This is my setup:
Computer -> M-audio 2x2m (interfaces and draws power via USB C) -> Line out (Left & Right) -> SBX 10 Subwoofer (TRS Input, Left & Right) -> TRS output into XLR input of speakers -> Genelec Active monitor speakers.

I've tried switching out my power bar for a surge protector one (grounded of course), tried different high-end cables (thinking it was EMI), etc. Recently I've noticed that the buzzing is more intense when my GPU is working harder, hence I think that it's probably some kind of EMI going on inside of my computer.

Might also be worth pointing out that when disconnecting the audio interface from the usb and powering via a power bar makes the noise go away. Turning the computer off while still using the usb port eliminates the noise as well (the usb ports still supplies power when the computer is turned off).

As a non-electro engineer I've ran out of ideas on how to fix this.

Is there a device out there that can be used as a filter for either my TRS cables or USB-C to eliminate this noise? Or does anyone have any other clue on how to eliminate this?

Thanks!

Comment: For troubleshooting, simplify your setup as much as possible. A portable device with line in and headphone out, connected directly to the M-Audio, would be a simple way to check if the problem lies within the M-Audio itself or not. That's step one.

Comment: I should probably have clarified that the setup is not buzzing when standalone, i.e connected to a power bar or when the computer is turned of (the usb still provides power in this state)

Comment: Have you made sure that all mains power in the system comes from the same power point? Otherwise you might get ground loops

Comment: @DirkBruere Yes, everything is connected to the same power bar

Comment: Does your computer have a fully metal case (i.e. no transparent windows) with all the panels on? Is the I/O shield installed? Have you tried front panel and back panel USB ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a Beheringer HD400. It's something to do with grounding. Mines was really bad when I used my mouse! Put it with it for years. Got my HD400 today plugged it all in and there is 100% no static noise anymore! I even changed my socket at wall to a double one! It's like 30 quid so just get it! They are quite hard to get but if it in the UK or Europe baxmusic have them!

Comment: Awesome tip man, just what I was looking for. I'm gonna order one and see if it works. Was actually available on Thoman so it was possible to ship to Sweden as well. Will let you know how it works out!

Comment: By the way, I am running an amp simulator but I guess I have to put this device in between the line out and line in rather than amp out and amp in? The description of the device didn't really clarify what ampages this device could handle

Comment: I am a total untechy guy so excuse my ignorance with the lingo. I have a usb interface that I use with my mac. I have 2 monitors that I plug straight into the interface but this is where I get lot of static! The hd400 is not powered so doesn't need to be plugged in. The are 2 inputs and 2 outputs on the hd400 so plug from the usb to the hd400 then plug to ur monitors.

Comment: Extremely easy and when I plugged them in to start with because I couldn't hear any static I thought I'd done it wrong so opened up logic and the music came out my speaker. It's a magical bit kit! That much so I've read countless people that had the same probs as me so felt the need to help out. If this doesn't work 100% if be very surprised 

Comment: Unsure about ampged sorry

Comment: I realized I never got back regarding this. I have two Behringer HD400 now and all my problems are gone. I placed one in between the audio interface and my active speakers, and one in my guitar signal chain. Once again; thanks for the tip! Unfortunately I'm too low rated to do upvote your answer, but it's accepted at least :)